# How to set Outline Level programmatically

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I try to set Outline Level for list, programmatically from code behind with Vsto C# [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the Outline Level using this code here:

```
Application.ActiveDocument.Styles["MyStyle"].ParagraphFormat.OutlineLevel =
    WdOutlineLevel.wdOutlineLevel2;
```

The enum `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdOutlineLevel` contains all the levels that can be set.
(And maybe you should also add some additional error handling that fits your needs.)

Comment: thank you i just mention there are outlinelevel in paragraph object too, i use `paragraph.OutlineLevel = WdOutlineLevel.wdOutlineLevel2`